# Real Time Chat using Socket IO - gifted chat performance

Tags: node.js, react-native, performance, socket.io, react-native-gifted-chat

I have Nodejs backend and Im using socket io in it the user can get all his chats from a single endpoint

so in react native im building the app with socket io and gifted chat ui and I'm using rtk query to hit the endpoint and cache the data.

I have a performance Issue when sending the message I feel like it's not quick, let me also tell you how this works in the app when I get all the chats I navigate to the selected chat and also get all chats in the chat screen (since its cached) and then select the chat that the user selected,

now lets say user A is the main user right now and he messaged user B so I send the message to my backend using socket and then the socket sends it to User B while saving it in the database ,

now I change the cache on the user A device and then rerender the whole chat screen And I think thats why it feels very slow when i send message.

so Is there is any way to make things smoother should I change my backend logic because I get when selecting from all chats its not great idea especially when changing the cache of it , it takes time. is using anything beside gifted chat will make things better ?